# SQL Recursive CTE Lookup in Hierarchy to get a Part Only Flat BOM

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I am trying to create a part only flat level Puchase/Manufacturing BOM from a Hierarchal Engineering BOM. the Database is set up with a PARTMASER table the lists all partnumberss and a BOMLEGER table that has the PARENT, CHILD columns for all assemblies. I am using the following code to get my flat BOM

```
WITH cteBuildPath AS
   (
   --=== This is the "anchor" part of the recursive CTE.
     -- The only thing it does is load the Root Node.
      SELECT ROOT.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE, ROOT.CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE, ROOT.BOMLEGER_QTY
       FROM BOMLEGER ROOT
       WHERE ROOT.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE LIKE '%10550-03A%'--The Root Node
    UNION ALL
     --==== This is the "recursive" part of the CTE that adds 1 for each level
     -- and concatenates each level of EmployeeID's to the SortPath column.
      SELECT 
            PARENT.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE, 
            --CHILD.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE as SUBPARENT,
            CHILD.CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE, 
            CONVERT(decimal(6,2),PARENT.BOMLEGER_QTY*CHILD.BOMLEGER_QTY)
       FROM 
            cteBuildPath PARENT, 
            BOMLEGER CHILD
       WHERE PARENT.CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE = CHILD.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE
   )
   --=== This final SELECT/INTO creates the Node # in the same order as a
     -- push-stack would.
SELECT PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE AS PARENT, 
--SUBPARENT,
CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE AS CHILD, 
SUM(BOMLEGER_QTY) AS "Total QTY"

 FROM cteBuildPath
  GROUP BY PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE, CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE
  ORDER BY PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE, CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE;
```

and I get the result

| PARENT | CHILD | Total QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10550-03A | CMP-0000003 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000816 | 8.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000817 | 8.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000834 | 24.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000835 | 24.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000840 | 24.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000866 | 6.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000868 | 8.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000872 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0000874 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0001047 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | HARD-0001103 | 8.00 |
| 10550-03A | MECH-0001409 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000131 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000132 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000133 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000134 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000135 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000136 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000137 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000138 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLT-0000139 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | PLUMB-0001378 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | PUR-0000003 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | PUR-0000004 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | PUR-0000005 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | PUR-0000006 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000138 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000139 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000140 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000141 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000142 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000143 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000144 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000145 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000146 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000147 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000148 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000149 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000150 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000151 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000152 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000153 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000154 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000155 | 4.00 |
| 10550-03A | STR-0000156 | 2.00 |
| 10550-03A | SUB-0000018 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | WLD-0000120 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | WLD-0000122 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | WLD-0000123 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | WLD-0000124 | 1.00 |
| 10550-03A | WLD-0000125 | 2.00 |

The issue is I am getting all the mid sub-assemblies in my result and I don't want them. So the SUB-0000018 is a midlevel Subassembly with children so since the Children are in the output I dont want the Subassembly.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a `NOT EXISTS` to the final `SELECT` to check if it's the bottom level part.

```sql
WITH cteBuildPath AS
(
   --=== This is the "anchor" part of the recursive CTE.
     -- The only thing it does is load the Root Node.
      SELECT
        ROOT.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE,
        ROOT.CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE,
        ROOT.BOMLEGER_QTY
      FROM BOMLEGER ROOT
      WHERE ROOT.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE LIKE '%10550-03A%'--The Root Node

    UNION ALL

     --==== This is the "recursive" part of the CTE that adds 1 for each level
     -- and concatenates each level of EmployeeID's to the SortPath column.
    SELECT 
        PARENT.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE, 
        CHILD.CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE,
        CONVERT(decimal(6,2), PARENT.BOMLEGER_QTY * CHILD.BOMLEGER_QTY)
    FROM 
      cteBuildPath PARENT
    JOIN BOMLEGER CHILD
        ON PARENT.CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE = CHILD.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE
)
   --=== This final SELECT/INTO creates the Node # in the same order as a
     -- push-stack would.
SELECT
  PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE AS PARENT, 
  CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE AS CHILD, 
  SUM(BOMLEGER_QTY) AS "Total QTY"
FROM cteBuildPath bp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM BOMLEDGER_ROOT child
    WHERE child.PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE = bp.CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE
)
GROUP BY
  PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE,
  CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE
ORDER BY
  PARENT_PARTMASTER_CODE,
  CHILD_PARTMASTER_CODE;
```